# Resources on solid state laser resonator design and modelling

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, laser

I'm an experimentally oriented physics student and have been fascinated by lasers for a longer time. I'm currently building a diode-pumped, frequency-doubled Nd:YVO4 laser from scratch. Before I start fiddling with the delicate optics and possibly shoot up some expensive parts, I'd like to model the laser cavity on a sheet to find out the optimal parameters.

The only good resource I found is [optique-ingenieur.org](http://www.optique-ingenieur.org/en/courses/OPI_ang_M01_C03/co/OPI_ang_M01_C03_web_1.html) which covers basic topics like the rate-equation and threshold conditions as well as the ABCD matrix formalism.

This is the direction I need further information in, especially the following points:

- how I can extend the ABCD matrix method when both the fundamental and the second harmonic are circulating in the cavity ?
- optimal cavity length
- beam waist and divergence
- resonator stability, sensitivity to misalignments
- slope efficiency (pump power vs. anticipated output power)
- in future: thermal effects (Thermal lensing, crystal fracture)

Where possible, I want to model it by hand and don't use simulation software.

The cavity will be of linear type:

|PUMP+OPTICS|--|HR@w| Nd:YVO4 |HR@2w|---|LBO for SHG|---|OC (HR@w,HT@2w)|

I would be very happy if anyone knew some useful books or resources towards these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book "Lasers" by Siegman is a good book to use.  I see you're using LBO, you'll need a lot of fluence, so you'll most likely have to place a waist in the LBO crystal.  This would imply that at least one, or both, of the end mirror are curved to produce such a waist. In the alternative you could use a lens and one mirror could be curved.

Any thermal lensing is going to play a role of shifting the waists, and mode sizes.  "Solid State Laser Engineering" by Kochner is another good, practical, source.